# How to add background image in LoginOverlay in vaadin 13?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I am using Vaadin 13s' new component LoginOverlay. I want to add background image using setTitle() as shown here.

```
        loginOverlay = new LoginOverlay();
        loginOverlay.setOpened(true);
        Component titleComponent = new Image();
        ((Image) titleComponent).setSrc("frontend/img/seven-oceans.jpg");
        loginOverlay.setTitle(titleComponent);
        loginOverlay.setDescription("Insert Employee Id and Password");
        loginOverlay.setAction("login");
        loginOverlay.addForgotPasswordListener(e->{
            Notification.show("Forgot password not yet handled", 30, Notification.Position.TOP_CENTER);
        });
        add(loginOverlay);
```

But, no image is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `loginOverlay.setOpened(true)` **after** setting the title component.

Reason: If you have a look at the `setTitle(Component component)` method implementation it says:

```
if (!this.isOpened()) {
     if (this.title != null) {
          this.title.getElement().removeFromParent();
     }

     this.title = title;
     if (title != null) {
          title.getElement().setAttribute("slot", "title");
          this.getElement().appendChild(new Element[]{title.getElement()});
     }
 }
```

So the `setTitle()` call doesn't do anything if the form is already "opened".

Not relevant for the image to be displayed, but as an improvement you also can change

```
Component titleComponent = new Image();
((Image) titleComponent).setSrc("frontend/img/seven-oceans.jpg");
```

to

```
Image titleComponent = new Image("frontend/img/seven-oceans.jpg", "alt text");
```

So the final code looks like:

```
loginOverlay = new LoginOverlay();
Image titleComponent = new Image("frontend/img/seven-oceans.jpg", "alt text");
loginOverlay.setTitle(titleComponent);
loginOverlay.setDescription("Insert Employee Id and Password");
loginOverlay.setAction("login");
loginOverlay.addForgotPasswordListener(e->{
            Notification.show("Forgot password not yet handled", 30, 
              Notification.Position.TOP_CENTER);
        });
loginOverlay.setOpened(true);
add(loginOverlay);
```

Result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS

Not only can you set a background-image for the title part, I can also recommend defining a background image for the big gray part surrounding the login form. You can of course choose to define only one of the two backgrounds.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/vaadin-login/theme/lumo/vaadin-login-overlay-styles.html">
<dom-module id="login-with-background-image" theme-for="vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper">
    <template>
        <style>
            /* this will add bg image to title part */
            [part="brand"] {
                background-image: url(../images/login-title-banner.png);
                background-size: contain; /*or cover, your choice*/
            }
            /* this will add bg image to surrounding grey area */
            [part="backdrop"] {
                background-image: url(../images/login-background-image.jpg);
                background-size: cover;
            }
        </style>
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

it will then look like this: (my choice of example images was maybe not optimal here, especially for the title background. But I hope it gets the point across)
[image]

Comment: where is the css in the project. how is it imported?

Comment: @d2k2 check out [Where should I place my static files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57553974/3441504). In this example (Vaadin 13), I imported it with `@HtmlImport`, because the styles are encapsuled in a `.html` file. In Vaadin 14+ I would define the styles in an actual `.css` file, and import it in the LoginView with `@CssImport(value = "./styles/loginOverlayWrapper.css", themeFor = "vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper")`

Comment: How is this achieved with vaadin 20+?

Comment: @kolle_86 I haven't tried 20+ yet, but I would assume it's done the same way as 14

Comment: Yes, in Vaadin 22.0.1 it works the same way: import the css file with @CssImport (at your `LoginView` class) and add your styles for the parts into that css file.